# Android GridLayoutManager with fixed sized elements and scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am trying to implement a minefield for a minesweeper game I'm developing for android. I am using a recyclerview and have tried the GridLayoutManager, however I am unable to scroll horizontally and vertically at the same time, as the views inside are resized.

I have also looked at the [FixedGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/recyclerplayground/layout/FixedGridLayoutManager.java), but when there are too many views on the screen, I am able to scroll past the left and right bounds and animations stop working.

Where should I start if I want to extend the GridLayoutManager to enable fixed sized views and horizontal + vertical scrolling?

Comment: Some code would be useful